# ASP.NET Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm working on a Web Site project (not Web Application) under Visual Web Developer Express Edition 2008 and using C# as the language.

In the web site I'm having a reference to a Service (an ASMX file in a server). When I run the application locally it can show the Default.aspx with no problems but when I upload it to my hosting site it gives me a "Compilation Error":

```
Compilation Error    
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.     
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    
Source Error:    
[No relevant source lines]    
Source File: App_WebReferences.doheyfto.0.cs    Line: 791
```

I don't why it's giving this error, I used this same Service reference in a Web Application project and it works fine.

I tried manually adding the reference to System.ServiceModel.Web to my project and also copying the corresponding DLL file to the BIN folder but then I get an error on a different namespace, I think this is not the solution, I guess that the namespaces that are referenced (from the .NET Framework) should be added automatically to the project, shouldn't it work like that?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I found something interesting, it looks like the web site is referring to the path of the Dlls from my computer, it's not trying to use the DLLs from the hosting provider's computer

Answer (score 0):

[System.ServiceModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.aspx) only exists in .NET 3.0 or higher. You should make sure your hosting provider supports at least that version of the framework.

Comment: Thanks Frederic, the provider does support Framework 3.5. I have another application deployed on the same server using 3.5 and everything works great.

Comment: Nope, it's targeting 3.5, I just verified, also I don't have .NET 4 installed and runs fine locally

Comment: Mmmkay, what about IIS? Did you check on your hosting provider that your web application uses the `2.0` runtime and not `1.1`?

Comment: I'm sure the hosting provider is not targeting 1.1 because I also used a Service reference on a different project deployed on the folder where I have deployed the web site now and it worked great. could it be a problem that before my web site I had a web application deployed on that same folder? I deleted everything on that folder before deploying the web site. Also, keep in mind that it worked great before I added the web reference

Comment: I added a comment on my post above, please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that System.ServiceModel assembly is also included in web.config under compilation tag - something like

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true">
   <assemblies>
     ...
     <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Thanks, that line was not included under the compilation tag. I added it manually but I got an error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Curro, my apologies - service model was 3.0.0.0 assembly - so it should have been "System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"